# Scoped Omniauth routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

Is it possible to scope omniauth paths to a resource?  For example, let's say we have an arbitrary website building website, where I can scope the website in routes via something like:

```
get ":site_name", :to => "sites#show"
```

I now want to add authentication via omniauth, but have it work on each individual site, so if I could specify the omniauth routes manually, it might be:

```
get ":site_name/auth/:provider", :to => "omniauth#whatever"
get ":site_name/auth/failure", :to => "omniauth#failure"
get ":site_name/auth/:provider/callback", :to => "my_omniauth_callbacks#auth"
```

We have tried using the path_prefix like so:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  configure do |config|
    config.path_prefix = "/:site_name/auth"
  end

  # Providers
end
```

but it just means we have to visit `/:site_name/auth/provider` instead of being able to use `/my_site_1/auth/provider`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to accomplish this with the following omniauth initializer (including configuration for google openid provider, though the same concept would probably apply to other providers):

```
require "openid/store/filesystem"

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  AUTH_REGEX = /^\/([^\/]+)\/auth\/([^\/]+)$/
  CALLBACK_REGEX = /^\/([^\/]+)\/auth\/([^\/]+)\/callback$/
  SITE_REGEX = /^\/([^\/]+)(?:\/auth\/([^\/]+)\/callback)?/

  configure do |config|
    config.on_failure = lambda do |env|
      match_data = SITE_REGEX.match env["PATH_INFO"]

      if match_data
        provider = match_data[2] || "unknown"
        location = "/#{match_data[1]}/auth/#{provider}/failure"
      else
        location = "/unknown/auth/unknown/failure"
      end

      Rack::Response.new(["302 Moved"], 302, "Location" => location).finish
    end
  end

  callback_path = lambda do |env|
    env["PATH_INFO"] =~ CALLBACK_REGEX
  end

  request_path = lambda do |env|
    match_data = AUTH_REGEX.match env["PATH_INFO"]

    if match_data
      "/#{match_data[1]}/auth/#{match_data[2]}/callback"
    end
  end

  provider :openid, :name => "google",
                    :identifier => "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id",
                    :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new("/tmp"),
                    :callback_path => callback_path,
                    :request_path => request_path
end
```

This will utilize the site name in the callback, the original auth link, as well as the failure link.  It can then be paired with the following routes in routes.rb:

```
get "/:site_name/auth/:provider/failure", :to => "my_omniauth#failure"
post "/:site_name/auth/:provider/callback", :to => "my_omniauth#callback"
```

Answer (score 0):

I find another way by override omniauth `path_prefix` method

```
module OmniAuth
  module Strategy
    def path_prefix
      @path_prefix ||= custom_path(:path_prefix) || OmniAuth.config.path_prefix
    end
  end
end
```

The `custom_path` is a method that `omniauth` use for set options with lamda functions.

Then just create a lambda function as an option in your provider.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  PATH_PREFIX_REGEX = /^\/([^\/]+)\/auth\//

  path_prefix = lambda do |env|
    match_data = PATH_PREFIX_REGEX.match env["PATH_INFO"]

    if match_data
      "/#{match_data[1]}/auth"
    end
  end

  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'], path_prefix: path_prefix
```

In this way `omniauth` gem build for you `authorize_path` and `request_path` as always.